# How to get Unity's new input system to work while editor is not focused?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I need to debug some input on my game while having Visual Studio focused.

However, that doesn't work; gamepad input is fed to the game only if Unity editor is focused.

Tried to follow these but without success:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/manual/Settings.html#background-behavior

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/manual/Settings.html#play-mode-input-behavior

Also checked `Application.runInBackground` and it is set to `true`.

**Question:**

How can I get the new input system to work while Unity editor is not focused?

Comment: The behavior sounds perfectly normal. Imagining a FPS game, if you're debugging in VS and moving the mouse, it's not also aiming inside the game, correct?

Comment: @TheNomad you should read the documentation before making such statement.

Comment: I did and seems I was right about the second part, but I admit I don't use gamepads and assumed it's the same. My bad there. `Application.runInBackground` isn't checked in the Editor for input feeds. Please check `canRunInBackground` on the gamepad and print it in the console and tell us if it's set to `true`.

Comment: Though it does run in the background, it appears that the feature isn't implemented when looking at the sources...